# Handle Android file reception on bluetooth

Tags: android, file-io, bluetooth

I need a way to send two files from an Android based telephone to another and **do something once those files are received**. 
In the first phone, the server, I used for simplicity the ACTION_SEND Intent, so I do not have to manage the bluetooth connection, discovering new devices and manage paired devices. IT WORKS! (here is the code)

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, files);
intent.setPackage("com.android.bluetooth"); 
intent.setType("image/jpeg");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Files"));
```

In the client phone I use the ACTON_DISCOVERABLE Intent for the same reason,

```
Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 120);
startActivity(discoverableIntent);
```

It works again, I receive the two files, but here is the problem:

They stored in the default bluetooth folder, while I need them to be in my app specific folder which is in the SD-Card.

**I have to change their location and rename them.** How can I do, or better, I know how to do that but, **How could I know when the transfer is finished?** Is there a way to capture the download finished event ?

(If you have the longer way solution to manage the entire bluetooth low-level process, is very accepted, but please I'm very noob with Android so explain me well the entire listing)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One very simple trick would be to move the file from default bluetooth folder to your desired one after the download has been completed, but im sure uve already thought of this.

Now, sending a file via bluetooth applies the same logic as sending some bytes. There is a simple library here [bluetooth_library](http://simonguest.com/2013/04/19/transferring-data-via-bluetooth-on-android-android-btxfr/) and an example on how to use it here [example](https://github.com/simonguest/btphototransfer-sample/blob/master/src/com/simonguest/BTPhotoTransfer/MainActivity.java) on sending/receiving files using bluetooth. It gives u the data as byte stream so you can save them wherever you wish to. I hope it helps

Comment: _One very simple trick would be to move the file from default bluetooth folder to your desired one after the download has been completed, but im sure uve already thought of this._ it would be a perfect solution, even not with great performance. BUT how can be sure the all two files are transferred ?